Find the time $t$ when the rate of change of $h(t)$ where $h(t)$ is the height of water , if the container is obtained by rotating $x=1+y^2$ about y

Consider a container of the shape obtained by revolving a segment of
the parabola $x=1+y^2$ about the $y-axis$ as shown below, the
container is initially empty. Water is poured in at a constant rate of
$1cm^3/s$. Let h(t) be the height of water in the container at time t.
find the time t when the rate of change of $h(t)$ is maximum

Source :- ISI UGB 2024

The maximum radius of the container is 2 and minimum is 1
I started by finding an expression for value
$dV= \pi r^2dy$, form the middle of the container
but $r^2=(1+y^2)^2$
so $V= \int_0^2 \pi (1+y^2)^2dy$
Or to a general height h
$V =\int_0^h \pi (1+y^2)^2dy$
so Actual volume is
$2V= 2\int_0^1 \pi (1+y)^2dy$
However, I'm not sure now to integrate wrt to the bottom which is what I think I need to do to solve this using differential calculus

I'd like to note that this is from an  exam for 12th graders, so no double integrals or anything of that sort please

The problem can be resolved with much of the math eliminated, purely by intuition.  The rate of change of the height will be maximized at the precise point that the cross-sectional area is minimized, which is when the radius is minimized.  So, all that you have to do is compute $~t~$ such that $~h(t) = 1$ cm.

@mathandphysicsforever, did you write ISI 2024?

@user2661923, this was a 10 marker, so not enough IMO

@aqualubix, yes I did

@mathandphysicsforever, come here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/153115/isi-cmi-2024

I don't understand what you mean by 10 marker.  If this is supposed to signify that you get partial credit for work shown, and the more work shown the better; there is a glaring exception to such a rule.  If you provide an elegant shortcut that is completely valid and completely solves the problem, the solution-evaluator must give full credit.  With respect to my previous comment, all that you have to do is create the Lemma that rate of change increases as the current radius decreases, and vice-versa, and then prove this Lemma.  Then, you must be given full credit.

"I'm not sure now to integrate wrt to the bottom" - I guess you mean that you realize $y\in[0,2]$ only covers the top half of the tank. You should have$$V(t)=\int_{-2}^t\pi\left(1+y^2\right)^2,dy$$
